# Definition of a vertex cover

Tags: graph, discrete-mathematics

Could someone explain to me the following definition of a vertex cover??

A vertex cover of G=(V,E), an undirected graph, is a subset $S\subseteq V$ such that each edge of G is incident upon some vertex in S.

Comment: What's the problem? Are there words you don't understand? Or you're not sure about some concepts?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a vertex cover as a set of vertices S so that every edge e in E has an endpoint in S (that's just rephrasing the definition).  As an example, if your graph is a star (one central vertex v, and n leaves, w_1, w_2, ..., w_n) with edges {v, w_i} for i from 1 to n.  A vertex cover could be any of the following:

S_1 = {v} because every edge contains v

S_2 = {w_1, w_2, ..., w_n}

S_3 = V

or just any subset of vertices containing v.